# Django отделить крон задачи от основного функционала

Tags: django

Есть сайт, работающий на django, и есть регулярные крон задачи, несколько десятков, которые иногда подгружают CPU память физической машины.

Появилась идея - поселить крон задачи на отдельную физическую машину, пусть живет своей жизнью, а сайт будет жить своей жизнью.

Как это сделать правильно и как в данном случае подружить миграции?

Comment: Выполнение миграций относится не к физической машине, а к базе данных — просто прописывайте правильные настройки подключения к вашей базе данных на всех физических машинах и всё. Ну и не забывайте делать миграции совместимыми с предыдущими версиями сайта, чтобы необновлённые физические машины не сломались

Comment: Про базу понятно, но немного не понятно про сам процесс миграций, например:

Есть исходники сайта
Есть исходники крон задач

В первом и во втором случае необходимо поддерживать актуальные модели, правильно ли я понимаю, что в данном случае для правильной связи использовать симлинки? Исходники живут в git репе.

Comment: Крон что конкретно делает-то?

Comment: Крон ходит в базу, обновляет записи в таблицах, добавляет записи.